# Numpy array in Keras Layer

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I want to adjust the image brightness of an input image that is feed into a keras model. The data is supplied from a simulator and feed into the model in real time so i need a way to adjust the image data in the model itself. I am currently using my own layer with openCV to perform the task but i am getting the following error.

> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 70, in _mean
>       ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount)
>   AttributeError: 'DType' object has no attribute 'type'

The issue appears to be with 'gamma = np.median(img) / 25' and the code trying to do numpy maths on a class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'.

My class code is

```
class ImageLayer(Layer):

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(ImageLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def call(self, img, mask=None):

    print(type(img))
    # adjust the image brightness to help normalise dark and light images
    gamma = np.median(img) / 25
    if gamma > 5.:
        gamma = 5
    elif gamma < 0.5:
        gamma = 0.5
    # build a lookup table mapping the pixel values [0, 255] to
    # their adjusted gamma values
    # http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/05/opencv-gamma-correction/
    invGamma = 1.0 / gamma
    table = np.array([((i / 255.0) ** invGamma) * 255
                      for i in np.arange(0, 256)]).astype("uint8")

    # apply gamma correction using the lookup table
    return cv2.LUT(img, table)
```

The model calls the class from the model

```
inputs = Input(shape=(160, 320, 3), dtype='int8')
x = Cropping2D(cropping=((50,0), (0,0)), input_shape=(160, 320, 3), dim_ordering='tf')(inputs)
x = ImageLayer()(x)
x = BatchNormalization(epsilon=0.001, mode=0, axis=2, momentum=0.99)(x)
```

Is it possible to do what i want to do?

Is it possible to perform numpy arithmetic in Keras? I know that you can in Tensorflow with .eval().

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, you take an image and then 1. crop it 2. change the brightness. Then feed it into your model. So instead of defining the Input layer of the shape `(160, 320, 3)`, why don't you define one of the shape that you will get after cropping and changing brightness. Then define the rest of your model as usual. If you do this, then instead of writing a layer, you will only have to write your own generator, in which you can change brightness/crop etc. using normal opencv/python/numpy. For example, see [my post](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/1638) for how to define a multi-threaded generator capable of working with multiple workers.

Do not do this if you want you want to treat the change in brightness as a learnable parameter or include it in backpropagation. In other words, use the above technique if the brightness change is a pre-processing operation and has nothing to do with how you learn.

A simple generator (works with only 1 worker) on MNIST data is given below which fetches 32 images at a time. You may include your brightness change operation immediately after you read the image. Treat this code only as a skeleton. I have not defined all the variables and it will not work out of the box.

```
def myGenerator():  # write the definition of your data generator
    while True:
        count = 0
        for i in range(len(allImgFilenames)):
            if count == 0:
                imgBatch = np.empty((batchSize, 3, 32, 32), dtype=float)
                labelsBatch = np.empty((batchSize,), dtype=int)
            img = cv2.imread(allImgFilenames[i])
            img = cv2.cvtcolor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)  # change the brightness
            img = np.float32(img)/255.
            imgBatch[count, :, :, :] = np.transpose(img, (2,0,1))
            labelsBatch[count] = np.random.randint(0,10,(1,1))
            count += 1
            if count == batchSize:
                count = 0
                yield (imgBatch, labelsBatch)
```

Call the generator in the `fit` function as follows:

```
my_generator = myGenerator()
print("Built the generator")

model.fit_generator(my_generator, samples_per_epoch=60000, nb_epoch=10)
```

**Testing:**

You want to get the data from simulator in real-time. For this, you can replace `cv2.imread()` by a function which gets the data from simulator. You may also change the batch size to 1, if you want to classify the image as soon as it is simulated. Fetch the image from generator as follows:

```
img, label = my_generator.next()  # this will give you `batchSize` number of samples.
model.predict(img)  # `img` should have 4 dimensions if RGB, img.shape = (1,3,nRows,nCols)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This helps when training and validating the model. It failed when i tried to run the saved model in the simulator. I know you could use "predict_generator" if you have the test data. Is there any way to get the real time data from the simulator and then run it through the generator?

Comment: Yes, you can. You can ask generator for samples and then use `model.predict()` or `model.predict_on_batch()`. See my edit.